# Anatomically Correct Hellmouth

Tags: creature-design, anatomy, anatomically-correct

The hellmouth is a great bizarre being that guards the entrance of hell. While only the face has been recorded, it is quite a face

They have two mammalian head, with the two maxillae opposing each other as the jaws. Beside these jaws are a pair of webbed talons that extend the cheeks. They have 4 eyes, ears, and nostrils, but seem to have only one mind

The most curious feature of this creature is that its wide mouth acts as a doorway: Anyone might see and pass through to the other side, wholly unscathed by its teeth and talons

**How does this awful creature's anatomy fit together?**

Comment: Do you mean that instead of having a lower jaw it has a second upside-down upper jaw, with its own eyes, ears and nose?

Comment: @Daron Yes, that's correct

Comment: So what exactly is the question? "How does it's anatomy fit together?" You already answered that by describing the anatomy. Maybe what does the rest of the animal look like?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Skeleton

This creature will need some unique structures to combine the parts of its anatomy. One sensible solution would be for the wrist of the talons to articulate with the skulls' jaw joints. This should provide adequate attachment for all parts

## Musculature

They will also need muscles to move their skeleton. This has a simple solution: Put a jaw ramus on each side of the wrist, and attach enlarged jaw muscles to that

## Viscera

They will need many. A solution could be found by removing one of its brains, freeing up the braincase. The other brain can also be reduced, providing more space for organs

The heart and lungs could be placed with the brain, alongside the spleen and other such organs. These lungs would take in air by the nares. In the other braincase would be the digestive organs. These organs would attach to the main gut via a pair of pores in the base of the main jaws, with one leading into the mouth, and another leading out of the anus. They would obtain their food from the demons of hell that care for them. With these viscera, these hellmouthes should be able to survive

Answer (score 2):

I would challenge your premise. "Hellmouth" seems to enter fiction relatively recently, though it goes back quite the long way historically in art.

In artwork, it is *clearly* a poetic interpretation of Hell by early Christians. It is not meant to be a literal depiction, but to turn the minds of the pious to the idea that to even flirt with a life that might lead you to an eternity of punishment is to be devoured by a giant beast... and that this is only the beginning. The mouth is no portal, in this imaginative telling... it *is* the Hell they are warned of, and only the beginning of torment.

When it enters popular fiction much later (probably within the lifetime of some of the readers of this answer), it is used merely to distinguish itself from other similar plotlines about heroes and anti-heroes traveling to this "place" of torment. The doorway itself needed a name, if only so that protagonists can perform expository dialogue. In these fictions, when it is depicted at all, it is depicted not as a mouth of some demon but just an entrance or dimensional portal. You can think of "mouth" being used in this fashion in the same way we might talk about the mouth of a bottle.

If you wish to have a more literal hellmouth, there is plenty of existing artwork to draw from... but there's just nothing to work with that is plausible or even disbelief-suspendable. I can already write the comic strips that make fun of it, with the poor hellmouth beast walking around and randomly-without-warning regurgitating heroes and paladins and so forth, absolutely no control. Can't even intimidate them, because they already know they'd just return to the other side of the door.